# Rust: очистить вывод в черном окне, которое по результату работы ".exe" (стандартный вывод?)

Tags: вывод, rust

Мне нужно чтобы программа очистила э... по-моему это называется стандартный вывод, но я не уверен, в общем это черное окно, оно появляется в результате работы ".exe":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно чтобы программа его очистили от прошлых ее выводов и продолжила работать далее (я хочу чтобы она вывела следующее сообщение уже на чистом экране).
Если очистить прошлый вывод нельзя, то меня бы устроило чтобы предшествующие сообщения были вне области видимости, а новый вывод стал первой строкой этого окна.
Я пробовал сделать это с помощью этого:

```
std::process::Command::new("cls").status().unwrap();
```

но это вызывает панику:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я гуглил прежде чем написать сюда. Мне не помогло все что по ссылке ниже.
Да, там были команды которые очищают мой терминал VS Code, но они не очищают черное окно по результату работы моего ".exe":
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837011/how-to-clear-the-terminal-screen-in-rust-after-a-new-line-is-printed

Comment: Так сходу надежный способ не скажу, но я бы копал в сторону уже готовых абстракций на ОС-специфичными функциями терминалов, типа https://lib.rs/console - вроде он винду поддерживает и там есть [clear_screen](https://docs.rs/console/0.15.0/console/struct.Term.html#method.clear_screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
console = "0.14.0"
```

**main.rs**

```rust
fn main() {
    // console = "0.14.0"
    let term = console::Term::stdout();
    term.clear_screen().expect("Не удалось очистить консоль");
    println!("Дальнейший вывод программы");
    //Код далее
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ваш код отлично решает мою задачу!